# Window starts with scrolled to the bottom Wordpress detailed page

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I have an issue where a specific page is starting with scrolled down at the detailed page of Wordpress.

Is there a way to overcome this issue?

What could be the cause?

I've tried:

```
$(document).live('ready',function(){
     $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 'slow');
     });
```

But it doesn't seem to work...

Comment: give use full url of page. maybe you have #about in url

Comment: yeah, if you have an id in the url, most browsers will take you to that id on the page.

Comment: view-source:http://coreoflife.connectingimages.com.au/uncategorized/bourke-2-day-col-training-workshop/#more-1128

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a hash in url that leads to the page like *#more-1128* in your example, then most browsers will automatically scroll the page to make element with id matching hash visible.

To get rid of this behavior, either remove/change id of element that has *id="more-1128"*, or remove the hash in the url/links that lead to your page.

BTW, don't use `$(document).live('ready')` it doesn't really make sense since `ready` event is fired only once when the page is loaded. `$(document).ready(...)` will be totally fine here.